# Redis connection closed after 5 minutes using docker-compose

Tags: docker, redis

I've got a simple Node.js application that I'm using docker-compose to run locally. It includes a Redis service using the official [Redis Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) (version 5.0).

My Node.js app is using the official [Node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) (version 14.17.5).

My custom Node.js application connects to the Redis service using [Node Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) (version 4.0.1). The Node Redis client is event based, and at the 5 minute mark is publishing the "end" event, indicating that the connection has been closed. I want the connection to be kept alive.

The connection is kept alive permanently in our staging environment which is using Kubernetes so I don't think it's an issue with the Node.js code. I suspect their is an issue with my docker-compose.yml.

I tried decreasing the Redis **tcp-keepalive** setting of my Redis application from **300** to **200** (seconds) but this didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

In the docker-compose.yml I added the following configuration to my Node.js service:

```
services:
  app:
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=200
```

Looks like the OS was timing out the TCP connection.